# Printing array elements one by one instead of printing array

Tags: javascript, json, console.log

I have .json file, but since it is very big, I will paste an example of how it looks like:

```
  [{"translations": {
        "ces": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "deu": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "est": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "fin": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "fra": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "hrv": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "hun": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "ita": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "jpn": {
            "official": "\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0",
            "common": "\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0"
        }}]
```

Original .json file contains more than 10 blocks like this. If you are curious, you can check the link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheRadioDept/technical-question/main/countries.json

I also have javascript code that reads values from this .json file using `require` method.

```
const enteredKey = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log('Key is : ', enteredKey);

/* Checking if number of parameters more than 0 */
/* Checking if entered translation key is supported by.json file. */
// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
if (enteredKey.length < 2 && enteredKey !== null &&  removeDuplicates(keys).includes(enteredKey[0])) {
try {
console.log(data.map(point => point.translations[0][enteredKey] ?
// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
point.translations[enteredKey].official: `No translation for ${ enteredKey }.`));
} catch (error) {
console.log('Cannot translate variable');
}
} else {
console.log('Incorrect key parameter');
}
```

When program runs, it takes an CLI parameter, let's say `deu` for example and returns all parameters(official names`) of this key in .json file.
Please note that on my local PC both .json and JS files are stored in the same folder.

What I need is instead of doing one console.log for the whole array of `keys` is to log(print) them one by one. I have tried using `for loop`, but since I am unfamiliar with .json structures I don't know how to make it print it individually.
This is `for loop` I tried:

```
for(i = 0; i < data.translations[enteredKey]; ++i) { 
console.log(data.map(point => point.translations[enteredKey] ?
// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
point.translations[enteredKey].official: `No translation for ${ enteredKey }.`));
```

}

The output was  `console.log('Cannot translate variable');`.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hi! Thank you for feedback. I have edit the question, hopefully it will be more clear now.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question! Looks like this question's answers will help: [*How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/) so this should probably be marked as a duplicate. Something along the lines of: `const result = data.map(({translations}) => translations[enteredKey]?.official).filter(v => v);
` which will give you an array of the `official` value of the object identified by the entered key for each element of the array, unless there isn't one in which case it's left out. Or ...

Comment: ...if you just want to print them out one by one: `for (const {translations} of data) { const value = translations[enteredKey]?.official; if (value) { console.log(value); } }`. (That's using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), if there are parts that look unfamiliar.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you! Where do I have to write this code `const result = data.map(({translations}) => translations[enteredKey]?.official).filter(v => v);`? I am not quite familiar with it, so I would appreciate if you can show me how to do it. And thank you for resource sharing!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. You'd include that code after getting `data` and wherever it is in your code that you want that array (if you do want an array).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh yes. I did that and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, You want to check for the enteredKey in the JSON you have and if key is available you want to print the `official key value` else `No translation available` text. If Yes, Then you can try this **:**

```js
const data = [{
    "translations": {
        "ces": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "deu": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "est": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        }
    }
}];

const enteredKey = 'deu';

const res = data.map(point => point.translations[enteredKey] ?
point.translations[enteredKey].official : `No translation for ${enteredKey }.`)[0];

console.log(res);
```